# Custom phone number - OTP authentication system in strapi v4

Tags: authentication, jwt, content-management-system, strapi

I have my own authentication system deployed on another server written with nodejs, that takes the phone number of the user, sends an OTP, then the user validates the OTP and gets logged in.

But I don't know how am I supposed to change Strapi's default authentication. I've found some answers on the web but many of them were for v3. Everyone is saying it is possible but no one is giving a detailed overview of how to implement this.

Does anyone know or should I quit strapi?

I've searched for the problem and got some results like [this](https://forum.strapi.io/t/phone-number-authentication-in-strapi-v4/24756). It is still not clear how to implement this.

To register or login, I want to call my own custom api for sending OTP and one for validating the OTP. After that the user should be logged in and get the jwt.

Comment: did you find anything?